# MKTIME, PHP date/timestamp YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: php, mktime

I need to query MySQL for the current date (from PHP) in `YYYY-MM-DD` format... anyone?

Comment: *(reference)* Date and Time Functions in MySql: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate and PHP Date Function: http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 56, accepted):

**MySQL [`curdate`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate):**

You can do in query:

```
select curdate()
```

**PHP [`date`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)**

```
echo date('Y-m-d');
```

If you want to pass your own date format:

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($your_date));
```

Comment: What if for selected timezone like Philippines, how do I implement that one?

Answer (score 3):

`date("Y-m-d")` should give you the current date in that format.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT CURDATE();`

Answer (score 0):

The function I think you are looking for is

```
$datetime = strtotime($MySQLDateResponse);
```

$MySQLDatResponse being the date you get back from MySQL.  This will give you a PHP time stamp.  You can then convert that timestamp into any date format you want.  For the one you listed it's

```
date("Y-m-d", $datetime);
```

Hope that helps